# Term for when someone gets overly pepped up and thinks he/she can do anything

Tags: word-choice, expression-choice

What is it called when someone gets encouraged by people around him/her or gets pepped up by the atmosphere around to the extent that he or she gets a wrong impression about his/her powers and capabilities (physical or mental), and probably gets out of control and starts doing crazy things in an effort to do the job right.

For example, I'm looking for something similar to filling in the following sentence:

> Don't get/be **_**, you can't drink all that in one go"

If there are various related words or expressions to be used in different situations, I would like to have all of them with appropriate examples. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

thinking that you can do more than you really can, can be called delusional, cocksure, overconfident...however none of these imply that the overconfidence was induced by other people.

Someone who allows other people to convince him that he can do much more than he really can could be called stupid, dense, simple-minded, foolish, daft and many more - unless he has some mental issues, in which case none of these apply: it would be someone being subjected to abuse.

To describe what you want you need to create a phrase, for instance "praise-induced delusion" or "pep-prompted cocksureness"

*EDIT:*

from comments to other answers it seems the OP wants the usage: "Don't get *_*, you can't drink all that in one go". Hence:

"Don't get cocky, you can't drink all that in one go"?  - this can be taken as advice or as a challenge, depending on too many variables to list

"Don't be stupid(or alternatives), you can't drink all that in one go" - disclaimer: use at your own risk

Comment: Never miss an opportunity to use a word like 'cocksure'

Comment: @user3306356 Why?!

Answer (score 3):

It's called *a [manic state](http://medical-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/mania)* (enthusiasm, often of an extreme and transient nature) in medicine. There is excessive energy, often accompanied by creativity, increased work output, sleeplessness, grandiosity, impulsiveness, even psychosis and thoughts and schemes that may lead to self-neglect. It is not induced by othe people, though, but lay people still refer to people with high energy levels (for whatever reason) as *manic*.

A more common and less specific term might be [**hyper**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/hyper-) (very excitable or nervous; overexcited; keyed up), or *hyped*, *revved up*, *keyed up*, or (one we use a lot in our household) **rabid**.

There's also **psyched**.

Hyper is defined in the [UD](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=hyper) as *a short term feeling of having lots of energy; one who is hyper usually does crazy/stupid things and laughs a lot. Often called a "natural high" and is caused by mutliple things: friends, sugar, lack of sleep, night, etc*

Comment: @MohammadSanei - please elaborate. I would like to help.

Comment: Is there an informal non-scientific equivalent for _manic state_ or _manic_?

Comment: *Hyper* or *revved* is what I'd recommend.

Comment: So could we say for example "Don't get hyper, you can't drink all that in one go"? Or should I replace hyper with something else?

Comment: @MohammadSanei - yes, you can. It's not perfect, but you can. Maybe now that the context you want is known, someone will come up with better.

Comment: Hypomanic describes the slightly less extreme, somewhat more functional state: Hypomania http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypomania

Comment: Mohammed, you should edit your question to add the sentence to fill in, so that your accepted answer fits the question. Then 'cocky' is the word that fits (over-confident).

Comment: @Mitch You're right, I should have done that. But I thought there might be a general word to describe such a situation since there is one such a word in my language (Persian): جوگیر (/javgir/)

Comment: @Mitch I can't figure out a good way to fit in the example sentence in my question. Can you please do the edit for me?

Comment: @MohammadSanei How was that? Happy New Year!

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps slightly obsolete slang:  "jazzed."  You could use "overconfident" for a less-than-manic description.

Answer (score 1):

The force exerted by those around the person is *peer pressure*, and is far more specific to that phenomenon than other suggestions here. Thus, you might consider rewording the sentence:

> Don’t give in to peer pressure; you can’t drink all that in one go.

While this doesn’t *quite* fit the grammatical location you wanted to put this term, it will carry the more specific meaning you’re looking for better than more generic terms for being overconfident.